# mysql leftjoin by max autoincrement id?

Tags: mysql, max, left-join

> **A) users**
>
> **B) subscribtion**
>
> **C) package information**

I've table where `B` is a link between `A` and `C` , the query selected from `A` where `B` has row id for `A`  and join `C` by `B` id .

---

***Full example :***

```
SELECT a.*,c.packageTitle
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN subscribe AS b ON (b.userid = a.userid)
LEFT JOIN package AS c ON (b.packageid = c.packageid)
```

my problem if user has multi subscription in `C`, i cannot get latest subscription row in loop query, i also used `MAX(c.packageid)` inside `SELECT` failed also .

---

> **Goal** : get latest record in B assigned by A id .

any advice is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you were far off by trying to use `MAX()` to obtain the record with the latest package ID (which assumes that this ID is an increasing auto-increment column).  In my answer below, the subquery identifies the latest package ID for each user record, using a `GROUP BY`.  This subquery is then used to filter the correct records from your original query.

```
SELECT a.userid, b.*
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN subscribe AS b
    ON b.userid = a.userid
LEFT JOIN package AS c
    ON b.packageid = c.packageid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.userid, MAX(c.packageTitle) AS maxPackageTitle
    FROM users AS a
    LEFT JOIN subscribe AS b
        ON b.userid = a.userid
    LEFT JOIN package AS c
        ON b.packageid = c.packageid
    GROUP BY a.userid
) t
    ON a.userid = t.userid AND c.packageTitle = t.maxPackageTitle
```

As a note, this query would greatly benefit from something called a Common Table Expression (CTE), which is available in other RBDMS such as SQL Server and Oracle.  A CTE would make the query much less repetitive and more readable.

Comment: plz consider i have over 100K records is this query safe on server memory  ?

Comment: What alternative do you have which will have a better peformance?  Anyway, this is just joining your 100K table to a simplified version of itself.  If your server can't handle this, it should not be in production.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough. In Mysql you just as you said put a max on the select along with a group by. So it would look something like:

```
SELECT username, id_info, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT a.username, a.id_info, c.packageTitle, MAX(package_id)
    FROM users AS a
    LEFT JOIN subscribe AS b
        ON b.userid = a.userid
    LEFT JOIN package AS c
        ON b.packageid = c.packageid
    GROUP BY a.username, a.id_info, c.packageTitle
)
```

Remember to list all columns in the select which are also being grouped, except the one on which you are taking the max, or the query will fail.

Comment: plz consider i have over 100K records is this query safe on server memory  ?